# find the biggest ball - detect object

Tags: python, object-detection

i am a newby in python and i am researching about detect object. I'm looking for the biggest ball. I have no idea how to make it work. Can anybody give me some pointers? Here is what I have so far.
my code: (from: "https://youtu.be/Vg9rrOFmwHo")

```
import cv2
import serial
from time import sleep


classNames = []
classFile = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/coco.names"
with open(classFile,"rt") as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n")

configPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/ssd_mobilenet.pbtxt"
weightsPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/frozen_inference_graph.pb"

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320) 
net.setInputScale(1/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)


def getObjects(img, thres, nms, draw=True, objects=[]):
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres,nmsThreshold=nms)
    if len(objects) == 0: objects = classNames
    objectInfo =[]
    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
            className = classNames[classId - 1]
            if className in objects:
                objectInfo.append([box,className])
                if (draw):
                    cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
                    cv2.putText(img,'sports ball',(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
                    x= int(box[0]+box[2]/2)
                    y= int(box[1]+box[3]/2)
                    cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 5, (0,255,0), 1)     
                  
    return img,objectInfo


if __name__ == "__main__":

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3,640)
    cap.set(4,480)

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        height, width, _ = img.shape
        result, objectInfo = getObjects(img,0.29,0.2, objects=['sports ball'] )
        #print(objectInfo)
        cv2.imshow("Output",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: What did you achieve already by the logic above?

Comment: Of course, by considering all balls are faraway the same distance from your camera, you could then calculate the area of the detected rectangle (of the ball object) by using the four points of the detected box `box[0], box[1],...` and if the previous area is less than the max area which should be initially zero - if so update the max are to be the current new one.